# Sum of time with result more than 24 hours

Tags: java, date, time, duration, hour

Suppose the following snippet:

```
LocalTime test = LocalTime.of(21, 14);
test.plusHours(5);
```

The result would be, normally, `02:14` but I want to sum beyond the 24 hour limit, so the result would be `26:14`.

In this case I have a field that an user can input how much time it spent on a task. However I have to work with hours (eg 48 hours) instead of days (eg 2 days and 4 hours).

Is there a way that I can achieve that within the `java.time` API? If not, what can I do to achieve that? I am using Java 8, with Spring Boot and Hibernate to map the database.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Sounds like an XY problem. (i.e."*what are you really trying to do*"?)

Comment: @selbie I have a field where user can input how much time it spent on a task. That time can be more than 24 hours.

Comment: The obvious solution is to normalize the user's input from what he types into a valid LocalTime object.  Or normalize everything to minutes.  (e.g. if the user types "26:14" as a time, you normalize this to `26*60+14` minutes and store that. Another conversion function to go from absolute minutes back to display time.

Comment: why not java.time.LocalDateTime?

Comment: `LocalTime` represents a time-of-day value. `26:14` is not a time-of-day value, but an elapsed-time value. Like the difference between a regular watch and a stopwatch. `Duration` is the class for tracking elapsed-time values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `java.time.Duration`

You’re using the wront data type for the value. You need a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html). `Duration` is the time-level counterpart of [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html):

> A time-based amount of time, such as '34.5 seconds'.

```
Duration durationTaken = Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
```

If you want to relate that to a date concept, such as to compute the end time, you can `plus` durations to date/time types:

```
LocalTime endTime = test.plus(durationTaken); //02:14
```

And you can do that with `LocalDateTime` too:

```
LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), test); //2019-02-07T21:14

//add the duration:
LocalDateTime endDate = startTime.plus(durationTaken); //2019-02-08T02:14
```

Comment: I searched for Duration before but I didn't get how I could make it work with Hibernate. And how could I make the sum later (I would have to convert fourth and back to a integer in the code?)

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify that in the question? Not sure it's very clear how you use that (just as an entity's data type?)

Comment: In the case I am using Spring Boot (to make an webservice) and Hibernate to map the database. When I read Duration docs I didn't "get" how it would work at first glance but I guess that I just have to figure it out.

Comment: @athosbr99 Do not store a duration as a time-of-day such as the SQL-standard `TIME` type. That is an abuse of the data type, and will confuse anyone reading your code. Instead, store a duration as a string, using the standard ISO 8601 format: [`PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to be using here. Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC means this class *cannot* represent a moment. When adding a duration you may get an incorrect (unrealistic) value as the result will be ignoring any anomolies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). Instead, use `ZonedDateTime` here.

Comment: @BasilBourque I ran the code and Hibernate maps the Duration type to bigint on PostgreSQL. dunno if should be like this

Comment: @athosbr99 The `Duration` class is designed as a pair of integer numbers: a total number of seconds for the entire duration plus a count of nanoseconds for the fractional second. So, yes, storing a duration as a long integer makes sense if you are willing to sacrifice the fractional second, and given that Postgres implements `BIGINT` as a 64-bit integer (SQL standard does not specify a length, unfortunately). When I suggested the ISO 8601 text format, I was thinking of `Period` for years-month-days which does *not* translate to a specific number like a `Duration` does.

Answer (score 5):

To specify how long a task takes, use [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html):

```
Duration initialDuration = Duration.ofHours(21).plusMinutes(34);
Duration afterFurtherWork = initialDuration.plusHours(5);
System.out.printf("Total duration was %2d hours and %02d minutes.%n",
        afterFurtherWork.toHours(), afterFurtherWork.toMinutesPart());
```

Update: as Ole V.V. points out, `toMinutesPart` was added in Java 9. If still using Java 8, use `toMinutes()%60`.

Comment: The `toMinutesPart` method exists since Java 9.

Answer (score 2):

LocalTime won't support this.  It has a static initializer with some very baked in rules around 24 hours.

```
/**
 * Constants for the local time of each hour.
 */
private static final LocalTime[] HOURS = new LocalTime[24];
static {
    for (int i = 0; i < HOURS.length; i++) {
        HOURS[i] = new LocalTime(i, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    MIDNIGHT = HOURS[0];
    NOON = HOURS[12];
    MIN = HOURS[0];
    MAX = new LocalTime(23, 59, 59, 999_999_999);
}
```

Based on your updated comments, I might suggest converting hours to your lowest time value, i.e. with TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(value).

Comment: Edited for clarity. I can change the type to anything else instead of LocalTime.